# Как узнать длину получаемого json через response headers?

Tags: javascript, json

Например, выполнив запрос по адресу https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments не могу найти какой из заголовков ответа (вкладка Network в Chrome) отвечает за длину данного списка

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: `json.length` ?

Comment: Никогда не встречал подобного заголовка. Или речь про [Content-Length](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Заголовки/Content-Length)? Его особенность в том, что его можно не передавать, вот он в конкретном случае и не передается. Да и длина списка будет не в штуках, а в байтах.

Comment: Никакой. В протоколе HTTP нет такого заголовка.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в этой строке `.then(json => console.log(json))` внутри json уже лежит массив, предложенный выше вариант `json.length` - это просто вывод свойства массива `length`, так как в `json` находится извлеченный `response.data`, это было сделано в строке `.then(response => response.json())`.

Способа узнать в заголовках запроса длину массива нет.

Вот полезные ссылки по работе [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) и работе [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Answer (score 0):

В вашем конкретном примере в заголовке ответа нет длины. если конечно сервер не зашифровал его для вас.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]